# Export ShieldUI Grid to MS excel and apply additional formatting

Tags: excel, grid, shieldui

I am using the ShieldUI Grid and came across some difficulties with exporting the contained data to Excel. The export actually works fine, but I need to be able to apply some more formatting to the exported data. There is no difference whether this will occur at or after the export itself; I just need to do it.
Will highly appreciate any clues and best- some code samples.

Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control supports exporting options, as described [here](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/settings/exportOptions/excel). This should cover the majority of scenarios.